# How to create a data frame with all ordinal variables as columns and with frequencies of specific event

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, frequency, sapply

I have an ordinal data frame which has answers in the survey format. I want to convert each factor into a possible column so as to get them by frequencies of a specific event.

```
I have tried lapply, dplyr to get frequencies but failed

as.data.frame(apply(mtfinal, 2, table))
```

and

```
mtfinalf<-mtfinal %>%
group_by(q28) %>%
summarise(freq=n())
```

Expected Results in the form of data.frame

[Frequency table with respect to q28's factors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5A9V.png)

```
Expected Results in the form of data.frame
q28  sex1  sex2  race1  race2 race3 race4 race5 race6 race7 age1 age2   
2     0                                                         
3     0                                                         
4     23                                                            
5     21





    Actual Results
    $age

      1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
      6   2 184 520 507 393 170 

    $sex

       1    2 
    1239  543 

    $grade

      1   2   3   4 
    561 519 425 277 

    $race7

       1    2    3    4    5    6 
     179   21   27  140   17 1307 
       7 
      91 

    $q8

      1   2   3   4   5 
    127 259 356 501 539 

    $q9

      1   2   3   4   5 
    993 224 279  86 200 

$q28

       2    3    4    5 
    1034  533   94  121
```

Comment: Did you check `xtabs`

Comment: No sir, Can you please elaborate or provide any links to do it, Regards

Comment: Please share sample data with `dput`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eyJf96Wgty1QI3dY4cxWzxKQN1_iptpo

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a count of number of unique combinations. What you are asking is impossible since there would be overlaps between levels of sex, race and age.

```
mtfinalf<-mtfinal %>%
 group_by(q28,age,race,sex) %>%
 tally()
```